# CSS - twice textbox in one line without margin

Tags: html, css

[image]

I'm want to remove margin between `Textbox` and `Date`

I try with

```
margin-bottom: -1px;
```

It's work but the date input width it minus 1px same

This my CSS

```
.sixs-comment {
  margin-top: 1em;
}

.sixs-comment .form-group .form-control {
  position: relative;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.sixs-comment .form-group .form-control:focus {
  z-index: 2;
}

.sixs-comment .form-group .comment_issue {
  resize: none;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 0;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 0;
  margin-bottom: -1px;
}

.sixs-comment .form-group .comment_method {
  border-radius: 0;
  margin-bottom: -1px;
}

.sixs-comment .form-group .comment_responsible {
  border-radius: 0;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 4px;
  width: 50%;
  float: left;
}

.sixs-comment .form-group .comment_finish_date {
  border-radius: 0;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 4px;
  width: 50%;
}

.sixs-comment .form-group .form-control:focus {
  z-index: 2;
}

.sixs-comment .form-group .comment_issue {
  resize: none;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 0;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 0;
  margin-bottom: -1px;
}

.sixs-comment .form-group .comment_method {
  border-radius: 0;
  margin-bottom: -1px;
}

.sixs-comment .form-group .comment_responsible {
  border-radius: 0;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 4px;
  width: 50%;
  float: left;
}

.sixs-comment .form-group .comment_finish_date {
  border-radius: 0;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 4px;
  width: 50%;
}
```

And this HTML

```
<div class="sixs-comment col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12">
  <div class="form-group">
    <textarea name="comment_1[issue]" class="form-control comment_issue" rows="3" placeholder="Textbox"></textarea>
    <input type="text" name="comment_1[method]" class="form-control comment_method" placeholder="Textbox" value="" />
    <input type="text" name="comment_1[responsible]" class="form-control comment_responsible" placeholder="Textbox" value="" />
    <input type="date" name="comment_1[finish_date]" class="form-control comment_finish_date" placeholder="Date" value="" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Base on Bootstrap 3

Hope someone will help me fix thanks

Comment: What margin? Show your complete code.

Comment: I have to update question.

Comment: Do you have a working code example to work with? Thanks.

Comment: I'm show the complete code in my post already.